# FAB is hiding under Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, floating-action-button, bottom-sheet

I have following XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:name="com.xyz.Fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_layout1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@dimen/global_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:name="com.xyz.Fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_layout2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/global_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/global_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/layoutBottomSheet"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The layout should appear as, `Fragment1` then below that `Fragment2` and FAB is anchored to `Fragment2` but, **above** `Fragment2` and not **under** it.

Actually it is showing as,

[image: screenshot]

What is going wrong? Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottomSheet"
        android:elevation="@dimen/global_margin"
        ...>
```

`layoutBottomSheet` probably has too much elevation, FloatingActionButton's default elevation is `4dp`, that's the reason your button is hidden behind the higher layout.

**Try a elevation value lower or equal to `4dp`**

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setCompatElevation(...)` on the FAB with a value higher than the bottom sheet elevation (which is 16dp if you're using `style="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal"`) to make sure it's at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I've added app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom" in the FloatingActionBButton and app:layout_insetEdge="bottom" in the View with the bottom sheet behaviour:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        />
```